# is there a minimum iOS version for debugging to work?

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

Debugging in VS works great with an iOS 8.2 device but not with an iOS 7.1.2 device.
Is it expected?

This is what I get

> Starting launch process C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\vs-mda\remoteDevice.js" --platform ios  --action launch --path "C:\Dmitry\Projects\SpreadBusiness\SourceCode\BlankCordovaApp11\BlankCordovaApp1\bld\ios\Debug\buildInfo.json" --serverUrl http://Squirrel.local:3000 --language en-US
>
> Timed out connecting debugger to remote Apache Cordova app. See Output window for JavaScript console output.
>
> Unable to find the app to debug. Check that the device is awake and unlocked.

***It is awake & unlocked as the app does get deployed and started ok**

> Requesting launch on remote iOS device for buildNumber 7821 on server http://Squirrel.local:3000...
>   running - Successfully ran on the device
>
> Requesting debug on remote iOS device for buildNumber 7821 on server http://Squirrel.local:3000...
>   undefined - Successfully Debugging on the device
>   {webDebugPort=9221}

Comment: The device where debugging does not work is an iPhone 4.

Answer (score 1):

Have you validated that debugging your app on the 7.12 device through Safari works? If that's the case, debugging through VS should work too since we don't restrict the OS version.

If the debugging through Safari doesn't work, make sure that your 7.1.2 device is enabled for debugging by going through Settings --> Safari --> Advanced --> Enable WebInspector.